# how to show some value on button from value of some variable using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Suppose I am having a variable who is getting some value on runtime ,I have some button on which I want to display that value from the variable using WPF/XAML.How will I be able to bind the content displayed over the button with the value of the variable.
Suppose button is show and variable is show_value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the content property of your button to the variable containing the string you want to show - ensuring you explicitly implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use  dependency property to update the value:

```
<Button Content={Binding variable_name} />
```

It is important to know your data context at this point.

Answer (score 0):

- List item

Bind using `ElementName`

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" x:Name="TBox"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding Text,ElementName=TBox}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

- Or if your variable can't be accessed from the UI just bind the button content to that variable :

-Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `Interface` in you code behind or in your view model,

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _value  ;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_value == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

-set the view `DataContext` using code

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

or via Xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

-update the UI so the button's Content is bound to the variable :

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>            
        <Button Content="{Binding Value}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```